# How to restrict Apache Location directive to cetain sub-domain?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mod-proxy, namevirtualhost

On our server `www.example.com`, we use the [`<Location>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) directive to proxy traffic to a back-end server:

```
<Location /app1>
  ProxyPass http://192.168.1.20
</Location>
```

Then we added a sub-domain `uat.example.com` which points to the same IP address of `www.example.com`. We want to use it as a proxy for client to test an app being developed. Hopefully, the client can access via:

```
http://uat.example.com/app2_uat
```

Now if we add a Location:

```
<Location /app2_uat>
  ProxyPass http://192.168.1.30
</Location>
```

The client can access both:

```
http://www.example.com/app2_uat
http://uat.example.com/app2_uat
```

How can I restrict Location such that only:

```
http://uat.example.com/app2_uat
```

Is accessible? (i.e. `http://www.example.com/app2_uat` should not be accessible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s easy to do if you use the `NameVirtualHost` option in Apache.  I have [a detailed answer provided for another user over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886644/apache-2-subdomain/19886686#19886686). The basic concept is you will be creating two different `VirtualHost` configs for each subdomain. Once you do that you can customize the configuration of both subdomains & achieve the granularity you are looking for.

**EDIT:** Adding details to how to setup `NameVirtualHost` for the original posters specific question details:

In general you need to first activate `NameVirtualHost` for the port you want. I will assume you will use port 80, so find this line in your Apache config—it might be in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`—& set as so:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Make sure your Apache config—chances are the same `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` as above—is set to list to port 80. Which should be the case, but adding here for reference:

```
Listen 80
```

Here is where the magic happens. Again, I am just doing the bare-bones basics so adjust to whatever your server settings are. This is for `www.example.com`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  <Location /app1>
    ProxyPass http://192.168.1.20
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

And now for `uat.example.com` create a new config like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName uat.example.com
  ServerAlias uat.example.com

  <Location /app2_uat>
    ProxyPass http://192.168.1.30
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

By using `NameVirtualHost` you can setup two separate domain configs tied to one IP address. Again, please review the answer I linked to above for more details.

Comment: Do you mean putting the `Location` block inside the `VirtualHost` block? Could you please put exact syntax in your answer?

Comment: Yes, place the `Location` block in the `VirtualHost` block.  But you are creating two new configs. One for `www` and another for `uat`.  Read my edited answer above.